# User authentication with zfcampus/zf-oauth2 module

Tags: php, authentication, oauth-2.0, zend-framework2, zend-framework3

I'm implementing the module zfcampus/zf-oauth2 with ZF3.
Everything that is documented ( https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-oauth2 ) is working as expected.

I would like to implement user authentication.

I've found that there is the 'password' grant type for this job but the call requires the client application id and secret.

This is a problem because if I have a third party application that needs to authenticate the user, the only method that I have to redirect the user to a login form and keep track of these informations is to send them in clear to the client side application, perhaps as a part of the querystring.

Obviously I'm not doing that.

So the question is, using the mentioned tecnologies, is it possible to make a call with the grant type 'password' without the 'secret' parameter?
Or, is there any best practices to achieve user authentication with zf-oauth2 module?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After some hours of research I think I can answer myself to this question.
Since Oauth2 was created to manage authorization rather than authentication I created within my Oauth2 server a separated controller just to manage authentication.

This controller will render a login form, check user data when submitted then redirect the user to a specified third party application location, bringing just a single value if the authentication was ok or not.

After receiving this event, with a positive authentication, the third party application can start the process of getting the authorization token and render the "Do you want to authorize" page to the user.

I didn't use the password grant that actually is not necessary within this implementation.

After the user authorize, the third party application will get the token that can be used to consume protected resources, for example to get the user data or anything in the token scope, that actually is my next step of study.

I'm still open to advices :)